# MQJE001: An MQException occurred: Completion Code 2, Reason 2059 MQJE011: Socket connection attempt refused, couldn't access IBM MQ

Tags: java, ibm-mq

[image: ibm mq screenshot]

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IBMMQTest obj = new IBMMQTest();
        obj.mqSend();

    }
    
    //method to connect and send message to Mq   
    public void mqSend(){
      try{

         //Create a Hashtable with required properties
         Hashtable properties = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
         properties.put("hostname", "127.0.0.1");
         properties.put("port", "1514");
         properties.put("channel", "APPQ1"); 

         //Create a instance of qManager
         MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("HBAX013D", properties);

         //Connect to the Queue
         MQQueue queue = qMgr.accessQueue("Q1", MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT);

         //Creating the mqmessage
         MQMessage mqMsg = new MQMessage();
         mqMsg.writeString("hello");

         MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();

         queue.put(mqMsg,pmo);

         queue.close();
         qMgr.disconnect();
      }catch(MQException  mqEx){
         mqEx.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

}
```

When I try the command `dspmq`, I get the following result:

```
QMNAME(HBAX013D)                                          STATUS(Running)
QMNAME(HBAX013DD)                                         STATUS(Running)
QMNAME(TEST)                                              STATUS(Ended unexpectedly)
QMNAME(TEST2)                                             STATUS(Ended unexpectedly)
```

My system ip: 10.25.25.7

I am using Oracle Java 8

When I try the command `telnet 127.0.0.1:1414` I get the following error:

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed.
```

Comment: my system ip: 10.25.25.7, i am using java 8 oracle , when i try the command telnet 127.0.0.1:1414 i got following error Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed.

Comment: The command should be `telnet 127.0.0.1 1414`.  You are listening on 1514, not sure why you are trying to test 1414?  What does `netstat -an | findstr "1514"` show?